# Calcular raiz cúbica

Tags: c#, .net, matemática

Estou a ter dificuldade a criar os seguintes botões Raiz cubica e LN. 
Tenho botões que devem ser muito parecidos como por exemplo a raiz quadrada normal e o log.

Tentei criar o seguinte para a raiz cubica:

```
   private void btn_raizcub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        primeiro += double.Parse(janela.Text);
        resutado = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(primeiro/3.0));
        janela.Text = resutado.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Pelo menos a raiz cúbica não está a funcionar correctamente dessa forma. Apesar de funcionar

Comment: Não me dá correcto nem com Sqrt nem com o Pow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fórmula correta para obtenção da raiz cúbica é:

```
Pow(primeiro, 1.0/3.0)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/son1Zk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RmrfEA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Division.cs).

Note que esse `double.Parse()` pode falhar, eu não usaria desta forma, o [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é mais adequado. É meio estranho criar um tipo de dupla precisão e usar um `Convert.ToSingle()`.